# How to clear a bind object without executing events

Tags: wpf, events, binding, unbind

I have a TextBox with a TextChanged event.
This TextBox is in a StackPanel.
If I make a StackPanel.Children.Clear(), the event of my TextBox is not executed.

Perfect for me!

Now, I need to bind my TextBox to the result of a database request.
If I make my StackPanel.Children.Clear(), the TextChanged event IS EXECUTED!

Who know I to avoid this execution when the TextBox is Clear() ?

The solution is to Unbind my TextBox WITHOUT EVENT EXECUTION...

Comment: Phenomenon itself is really interesting! Why is that? If the Binding reference leaving the TextBox alive, why the event is not enough to do this?

Comment: I have test your solution with the ClearAllBindings but the problem is the same.
The event TextChanged of my TextBox is executed when I ClearAllBindings().

Please, note that I use DataContext to bind my objects with my database.

Comment: It makes no sense, because nobody changes the text!

You're ready to show your XAML + code?

Comment: <Button Click="fermeture">Fermeture</Button>
<Grid Name="g">
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=report_number, Mode=OneTime}"  TextChanged="changement" Name="tb"></TextBox>
</Grid>
</StackPanel>

Comment: public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            set t = ...
            g.DataContext = t;
        }

        private void fermeture(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DependencyObject item in g.Children) BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(item);
            g.Children.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Clear done!");
        }

        private void changement(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Processing new Text value with Text = " + tb.Text);
        }

Comment: You write: _This TextBox is in a StackPanel_ ... i edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

clear before the binding:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(txtName, TextBox.TextProperty)
```

or better

```
foreach (DependencyObject item in sp.Children)
    BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(item);

sp.Children.Clear();
```

---

**EDIT - For nested elements:**

```
ClearBindings(sp);
sp.Children.Clear();
```

ClearBindings function:

```
void ClearBindings(Panel panel)
{
    foreach (DependencyObject item in panel.Children)
    {
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(item);
        if (typeof(Panel).IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType()))
            ClearBindings(item as Panel);
    }
}
```